# How to convert string date to DateTime format

Tags: elixir

How can I convert a string date like this

`"20201228"`

to something like this

`"2020-12-28T00:00:00"`

Comment: Use https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.html you can pass the format of the string as well there.

Answer (score 3):

You asked for "DateTime format" in the subject, so even though your example is a string, it's better to work with native date types if possible, so that's what I'll include here.

Since you don't care about time zones, [NaiveDateTime](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html) is useful, because it just represents an abstract date and time with no timezone.

```elixir
def to_naive_datetime(<<yyyy::binary-4, mm::binary-2, dd::binary-2>>) do
  [yyyy, mm, dd] = for i <- [yyyy, mm, dd], do: String.to_integer(i)
  NaiveDateTime.new!(yyyy, mm, dd, 0, 0, 0)
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.to_naive_datetime("20201228")
~N[2020-12-28 00:00:00]
```

---

If you really only want a string, you can skip the integer parsing:

```elixir
def to_iso8601(<<yyyy::binary-4, mm::binary-2, dd::binary-2>>) do
  "#{yyyy}-#{mm}-#{dd}T00:00:00"
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(2)> Example.to_iso8601("20201228")
"2020-12-28T00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sahil noted, using `timex` can be a simple option if you're used to the `strftime` format, e.g.

```
iex> Timex.parse!("20201228", "%Y%m%d", :strftime)
~N[2020-12-28 00:00:00]
```

However, if you want to avoid installing yet-another-dependency, you can write your own string parsing using pattern matching, for example:

```
iex> <<yyyy::binary-size(4), mm::binary-size(2), dd::binary-size(2)>> = "20201228"

iex> yyyy
"2020"
iex> mm
"12"
iex> dd
"28"
iex> Date.new(String.to_integer(yyyy), String.to_integer(mm), String.to_integer(dd))
{:ok, ~D[2020-12-28]}
```

If needed, you can construct your own `%DateTime{}` based on the parsed values:

```
%DateTime{
        calendar: Calendar.ISO,
        day: String.to_integer(dd),
        hour: 0,
        microsecond: {0, 0},
        minute: 0,
        month: String.to_integer(mm),
        second: 0,
        std_offset: 0,
        time_zone: "Etc/UTC",
        utc_offset: 0,
        year: String.to_integer(yyyy),
        zone_abbr: "UTC"
      }
```

Comment: `with <<y::binary-size(4), m::binary-size(2), d::binary-size(2)>> <- "20201228", do: [y,m,d] |> Enum.join("-") |> Date.from_iso8601!() #⇒ ~D[2020-12-28]`

Comment: Esoteric one: `~r/\A.{4}|..(?=..\z)|..\z/ |> Regex.scan("20201228") |> Enum.join("-") |> Date.from_iso8601!()`

Comment: Amazing.  Can you explain this regex?

Comment: First four symbols OR two symbols followed by two last symbols OR two last symbols.

Comment: If we're doing regex golf, I want to play too! `~r/\A(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\z/ |> Regex.replace("20201228", "\\1-\\2-\\3") |> Date.from_iso8601`

Comment: Same regex, different application: `~r/\A(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\z/ |> Regex.run("20201228", capture: :all_but_first) |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1) |> (&apply(Date, :new, &1)).()`